# Freeze WebRTC video stream and keep audio stream running

Tags: webrtc

Is it possible in WebRTC to freeze the video stream and keep the audio stream running at the same time?

By freezing the video I mean stop refreshing the video input for some time, keeping the last captured frame until I flag WebRTC to unfreeze.

Comment: Related https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/YG_3TjVQS3Y

Comment: Actually this thread contains the answer: remoteStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled=false

Comment: @user7116 please add the answer to get the points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this discussion on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/YG_3TjVQS3Y), it appears you would set the individual video stream's `enabled` property to false (likewise for audio muting):

```
// assuming `remoteStream` is on the other end
remoteStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
```

Note that this may blank out the video, rather than using the last captured frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
     function onRemoteStreamAdded(event) 
        {
        var stream = event.stream;

        if (stream.getAudioTracks().length) alert('Peer has audio stream.');
        if (stream.getVideoTracks().length) alert('Peer has video stream.');
                    stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;

        }
```

this should work